# Yarn: Never-ending build of fresh packages

Tags: yarnpkg

Has anyone experienced building packages that never ends? Not sure what the issue is but this happens every now and then. Happened to me twice and I am not sure how those instances got fixed. Now I want to document it just in case I or someone will encounter this again.

Here is the link of the issue:
https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/7779

Answer (score 21):

As strange as it may sound. I was having the same issue when I tried to install package using yarn through VS Code. when I hit yarn on the terminal it completed the process without taking any more time than it should.

Comment: This worked for me and I find that super weird! I wonder what about the VSCode terminal would cause this problem...

Comment: Not sure but it could be a bug or a permission issue, not completely sure.

Comment: It seems like it me be an issue of dangling processes according A. Johan's answer

Comment: maybe @Cameron, probably a tiny bug on the vscode which was fixed on later updates. But did not do an in-depth investigation on it.

Comment: Perhaps the version VS Code used is different than the version available at the terminal

Answer (score 17):

I experienced the same issue when running yarn install with Electron. The way to solve this was to run:

```
yarn cache clean && yarn install
```

while you are on MOBILE NETWORK, via hotspot. For some weird reason the normal network was giving issues.

Comment: yarn cache clean lasts a long time.

Answer (score 7):

I was using `node 14` (14.15.3) and changing it to `node 12` (12.20.0) fixed my problem.

Comment: Same here. I used `nvm install 12` and it was solved. Thanks!

Comment: Same here. `I used nvm install 14`. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This might take about 5-10 minutes depending on the speed of your Internet. Be Patient, it will be completed by saying-

```
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 231.31s.
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Alish, this happens in VS Code and I experienced it as well. After checking my running processes via `ps  -ax` I see a lot of yarn serve processes for by Vue app. Restarting VS Code fixed the issue. Seems to be dangling processes not properly terminated from the VS Code terminal

Comment: This seemed to be the case for me as well. I've had this issue a couple of times, and maybe it was a bit over-the-top but just restarting my machine worked.

Comment: @Cameron you can restart wsl from the command prompt. just type 

wsl --terminate <DistributionName> 

to stop a specific distro or

wsl --shutdown 

to stop all WSL distro.

Comment: Similar with me.  I had a lot of node-gyp processes running from being impatient with yarn adds and interrupting them.  Killed the node-gyp processes and package builds ran fine again.

Answer (score 2):

Downgrading `node` from version 19.* to the latest 18 fixed the problem

Comment: I used node 18.12.1 and it was solved. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

in my case issue was on `node v19.4.0`, when I changed to

```
yarn global add n
n 16.19.0
```

build of fresh packages became instant

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue while using a turbo monorepo and yarn workspaces. Turned out I had "install" defined as script inside one of my project package.json. Removing "install" as a script inside the package fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had Cypress in my `Package.json` and after running `yarn install`, it would get stuck in "[4/4] Cypress"
after a few hours of searching, this worked for me:

1. My Node JS version was 14, I upgraded it to the v18.12.1
2. I restarted the Laptop
3. I removed Cypress from `Package.json` and deleted the `yarn.lock`
4. I made sure that my Node version is upgraded by running this command `node --version`
5. Run `yarn install` again, and done :)

Answer (score 0):

for me I delete node_modules then run yarn cache clean && rm yarn.lock in my project then yarn install

Answer (score 0):

Another way this can happen is if you run out of space on disk.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `package-lock.json` if you have any as it interferes with yarn pkg. We had moved from using npm to yarn and this was the issue.

Answer (score -1):

in file next.config.js

you must put:

```
swcMinify: false
```

---

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: false,
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```